# Javascript comparison operator "not bigger"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to check if the hour of the day is between 8 and 23 o'clock.

I thought to write it that way:

if (8 < hour < 23) {...}

But it didn't work. Then, I have searched for comparison operators on the web. I didn't find, what I'm looking for. Do you have an idea, how to check if the hour of the day is between the borders?

Answer (score 3):

Use two comparisons with `&&`:

```
if (8 < hour && hour < 23) {
  ...
```

Comment: He might want "between 8 and 23" including them: `8 <= hour && hour <= 23`

Answer (score 1):

Try to split it up instand if making it  `8 < hour < 23`. Try this:

```
if (hour > 8 && hour < 23) {
      ...code....code...
    }
```